# Error initializing map

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, initializer-list

Okay so inside my ArcherArmor.cpp, I'm trying to figure out why the map initializer list isn't working, but for some reason I keep getting "Error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous". Here is my code:

I also have a class which ArcherArmor is derived from, that has a struct called `Armor`, which I left out for simplicity. The main problem is that error! The only thing I can think of is that im initializing the map wrong.

```
//ArcherArmor.h
#include <string>
#include <map>
class ArcherArmor
{
    private:
    map <int, Armor> soldier_armor;
    public:
    void ArcherArmor_shop();
};

//ArcherArmor.cpp
#include "ArcherArmor.h"
void ArcherArmor::ArcherArmor_shop(){
    soldier_armor = {//name, damage, price
            {1, Armor("Meito Ichimonji", 4, 150, 1)},
            {2, Armor("Shusui", 10, 230, 2)},
            {3, Armor("Apocalypse", 16, 300, 3)},
            {4, Armor("Blade of Scars", 24, 550, 4)},
            {5, Armor("Ragnarok", 32, 610, 5)},
            {6, Armor("Eternal Darkness", 40, 690, 6)},
            {7, Armor("Masamune", 52, 750, 7)},
            {8, Armor("Soul Calibur", 60, 900, 8)}
        };
}

//Main.cpp
/*code left our for simplicity*/
```

Comment: That is assignment, not initialization. Also if your keys are sequential integers, may as well just use a `vector`.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the clarification and a map is more suitable because I might end up changing the keys and stuff. This is just so I can get it to work, then I will work from there.

Answer (score 0):

The part of your code given here seems to be OK. I used a tuple type to replace your Armor type (not shown in your question), and the code compiles fine with gcc (4.8.1). I think the problem is elsewhere in your code.

```
//ArcherArmor.h
#include <string>
#include <map>

#include <tuple>
using namespace std;
using Armor = std::tuple<string,int,int,int>;

class ArcherArmor
{
    private:
    map <int, Armor> soldier_armor;
    public:
    void ArcherArmor_shop();
};

//ArcherArmor.cpp
//#include "ArcherArmor.h"
void ArcherArmor::ArcherArmor_shop(){
    soldier_armor = {//name, damage, price
            {1, Armor("Meito Ichimonji", 4, 150, 1)},
            {2, Armor("Shusui", 10, 230, 2)},
            {3, Armor("Apocalypse", 16, 300, 3)},
            {4, Armor("Blade of Scars", 24, 550, 4)},
            {5, Armor("Ragnarok", 32, 610, 5)},
            {6, Armor("Eternal Darkness", 40, 690, 6)},
            {7, Armor("Masamune", 52, 750, 7)},
            {8, Armor("Soul Calibur", 60, 900, 8)}
        };
}

int main() {
   ArcherArmor a;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your right, it runs on my mac(Xcode) also. So, I guess it's a Visual Studio problem.